# Setup the constrains between the UIView and UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I want to add view controller as subview inside the UIView . I have given the required constrains but I am not figure it out why it overlapping . Here is minimal code for it. I have given the top , bottom , leading , trailing constrains but not sure why it overlaps . **I want to put svc below the parentView**

```
  final class MovieDetailsDisplayViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let movieDetails: MovieDetails
    let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel

    init(movieDetails: MovieDetails, viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.movieDetails = movieDetails
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = parentView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let parentView = parentView()
        (view as? parentView)?.configure(movieDetails: movieDetails)
        
       childView()
        
    }
    
    private func childView() {
        let addHereView = UIView()
        addHereView.backgroundColor = .clear
        addHereView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(addHereView)
        let similarVC = SmiliarMovieViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        addChild(similarVC)
        
        // safely unwrap MySimilarViewController's view
        guard let similarView = similarVC.view else { return }
        
        similarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addHereView.addSubview(similarView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            addHereView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            addHereView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            addHereView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // height of the child content
            addHereView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170.0),
            
            similarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.topAnchor),
            similarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.leadingAnchor),
            similarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.trailingAnchor),
            similarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        similarVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    private class parentView: UIView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        let backdropImageView = UIImageView()
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        let overviewLabel = UILabel()
        let addHereView = UIView()

                
        private lazy var contentStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [backdropImageView, titleLabel, overviewLabel])
        
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            commonInit()
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }

        private func commonInit() {
            backgroundColor = .white
            addHereView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            addHereView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            backdropImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            backdropImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            
            titleLabel.font = UIFont.Heading.medium
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.Text.charcoal
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            
            overviewLabel.font = UIFont.Body.small
            overviewLabel.textColor = UIColor.Text.grey
            overviewLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            overviewLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            
            contentStackView.axis = .vertical
            contentStackView.spacing = 24
            contentStackView.setCustomSpacing(8, after: titleLabel)
            
            setupViewsHierarchy()
            setupConstraints()
        }
        
        private func setupViewsHierarchy() {
            addSubview(scrollView)
            scrollView.addSubview(contentStackView)
        }

        private func setupConstraints() {
            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backdropImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

                    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
                    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                    
                    backdropImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backdropImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 11 / 16, constant: 0),
                    
                    contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 24),
                    contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
                    contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
                    contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -24)
                ]
            )
            
            scrollView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 16, bottom: 24, right: 16)
            preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }
        
        
        func configure(movieDetails: MovieDetails) {
            backdropImageView.dm_setImage(backdropPath: movieDetails.backdropPath)
            
            titleLabel.text = movieDetails.title
            
            overviewLabel.text = movieDetails.overview
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for SVC code ..

```
class SmiliarMovieViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel

    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    lazy var titleLable: UILabel = {
        let titleLable = UILabel()
        titleLable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLable.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        titleLable.text = "Similar movies"
        return titleLable
    }()

    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let width = 100
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 200)
        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collection.dataSource = self
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.register(SimilierMovieCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SimilierMovieCell.identifier)
        collection.backgroundColor = .clear
        return collection
    }()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
        self.viewModel.updatedState = { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
    }
    
    private func setUpUI() {
        view.addSubview(titleLable)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        titleLable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        titleLable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLable.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width/2).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Here is the cell code ..

```
class SimilierMovieCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "CompanyCell"
    let columnSpacing: CGFloat = 16
    let posterSize = CGSize(width: 92, height: 134)
    
    let coverImage = UIImageView()
    let tagView = TagView()
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    
    let childStackView = UIStackView()
    let containerStackView = UIStackView()

    private func commonInit() {
        layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.Text.charcoal
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        
        coverImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        coverImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        coverImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        childStackView.spacing = 10
        childStackView.alignment = .leading
        childStackView.axis = .vertical
        
        containerStackView.spacing = columnSpacing
        containerStackView.alignment = .top
        containerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        setupViewsHierarchy()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    func setupViewsHierarchy() {
        contentView.addSubview(containerStackView)
        childStackView.dm_addArrangedSubviews(coverImage)
        childStackView.dm_addArrangedSubviews(titleLabel)
        childStackView.dm_addArrangedSubviews(tagView)
        containerStackView.dm_addArrangedSubviews(childStackView)
    }
    //Constraints

    func setupConstraints() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            containerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            containerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            containerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
            coverImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: posterSize.width),
            coverImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: posterSize.height),
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: coverImage.bottomAnchor),
            tagView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
    }
    
    func configure(movie: Movie) {
        commonInit()
       
        titleLabel.text = movie.title
        tagView.configure(.rating(value: movie.voteAverage))
        
        if let path = movie.posterPath {
            coverImage.dm_setImage(posterPath: path)
        } else {
            coverImage.image = nil
        }
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very confusing approach -- **First Tip:** add comments in your code explaining (to yourself) what the code should be doing. That way, when you post code asking for help, it will **also** be clear to anyone else. **Second Tip:** you are showing us a screen that does NOT look like what you want. Manually layout a screen (or use an image editor to draw it out) showing us what you DO want.

Comment: be more specific             svc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.bottomAnchor),
it not adding the constraints properly ..@DonMag

Comment: I want to put svc below the parentView . @DonMag

Comment: What is the "parentView"? Is it the big image with large title and paragraph of text? Your code includes a scroll view and a stack view... is ***everything*** supposed to be in one big scroll view? Or, is the big image/large title/paragraph supposed to be in a scroll view above and separate from the small images?

Comment: the parent view got image , text and scroll view , contentStackView etc . You see from screenshot I have collection view where you see the list of small image left to right and this view is called svc . I want to put svc content below the parentView @DonMag

Comment: Seems you setting your controller's `view` to an instance of `parentView()` and then creating another instance of `parentView()` in the `viewDidLoad()`.  I would remove the `view = parentView()` line,

Comment: You need to look at adding the "collection view controller" as a child controller. See: [`addChild(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild)

Comment: done but did not get the expected result .. @clawesome

Comment: @Nar - you rewrote all of that code into a proper `addChild()` structure in 20 minutes? And ended up with the same layout?

Comment: You cannot set up constraints to a view controller. It isn't a view and has no constraints. You can embed a view controller's _view_ in your interface, if you configure the view controller as a child view controller and the surrounding interface's view controller as a parent view controller.

Comment: It is totally unclear what `parentView` is supposed to be in this story. In the code you've shown, it is never even added to the interface. As things stand, you have two sets of code that conflict with one another. I strongly suggest you delete this question, take a deep breath, and ask the question afresh, this time supplying real code and only real code. Keep the concept of a [mcve] constantly before your mind's eye.

Comment: @Nar - when I said you need to look at `addChild(_:)`, I didn't mean just stick in a new line of code. I meant read up on it and learn how to implement it.

Comment: @DonMag it not good practice put every single logic into VieDidLoad function . Can you please suggest different way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, really quick example of using a child view controller...

We'll start with your "Similar" view controller. A collection view cell and a view controller that creates a collection view:

```
class MySimilarCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        [imgView, label].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        imgView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        imgView.tintColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
    }
}

class MySimilarViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var cv: UICollectionView!
    let data: [String] = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.itemSize = .init(width: 120.0, height: 180.0)
        cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)

        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(cv)
        
        // so we don't have to type so much
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180.0),
        ])
        
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.register(MySimilarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        
        // so we can see the collection view framing
        cv.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! MySimilarCell
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(data[indexPath.item].lowercased()).circle") {
            c.imgView.image = img
        }
        c.label.text = data[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }
}
```

If you set `MySimilarViewController` as your Initial View Controller and run the app, it should look like this:

[image]

Next, we'll setup the "parent" controller, with an image view, a title label and a paragraph label, in a vertical stack view, in a scroll view, with space at the bottom for the "child":

```
class MyMainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

        // add an image view, title label, paragraph label
        //  to a vertical stack view
        //      added to a scroll view
        
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.backgroundColor = .white
        imgView.tintColor = .systemOrange
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "swift") {
            imgView.image = img
        }
        
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 28.0, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.text = "Spirited Away"
        
        let paraLabel = UILabel()
        paraLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        paraLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
        paraLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        paraLabel.text = "A young girl, Chihiro, becomes trapped in a strange new world of spirits. When her parents undergo a mysterious transformation, she must call upon the courage she never knew she had to free her family."

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20.0

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imgView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(paraLabel)

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        // so we can see the scroll view's framing
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let addHereView = UIView()
        addHereView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        addHereView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(addHereView)
        
        // so we don't have to type so much
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // image view needs height
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            
            addHereView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            addHereView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            addHereView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // height of the child content
            addHereView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180.0),

        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Now, if we set `MyMainViewController` as the Initial View Controller, we should get this:

[image]

[image]

The image and labels are in the (yellow) scroll view, and we have a blue view where we're going to add the child controller's view.

So, at the end of `viewDidLoad()` in `MyMainViewController`, we'll add this:

```
    let similarVC = MySimilarViewController()
    addChild(similarVC)
    
    // safely unwrap MySimilarViewController's view
    guard let similarView = similarVC.view else {
        // this should never happen, unless we've really mis-written the detail view controller
        fatalError("Similar VC had no view!!!")
    }
    
    similarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addHereView.addSubview(similarView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        similarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        similarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        similarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        similarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    ])
    
    similarVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

So, we've added an instance of `MySimilarViewController` as a child view controller, and we've added its `view` as a subview of the blue view.

And we get this:

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit**

If you really, really want to stick with your current approach, couple suggestions...

1 - Set background colors to your UI elements, so you can see the framing.

2 - Learn how to use `Debug View Hierarchy` so you can figure out what's going wrong with your layout.

After adding (and "faking") the missing information from your post in order to run your code and see the layout, this is what we get:

[image]

and if we try to scroll the content up, it only goes this far:

[image]

Let's use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the layout:

[image]

You've replaced the controller's built-in view with "parentView" (blue) and you've constrained your scroll view (red) to the full height of the view.

You've then added "similar" controller's view as a subview, but it's on top of the scroll view.

So, in `parentView` -> `setupConstraints()`, get rid of the scroll view's bottom anchor:

```
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
//scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
```

Then, in `childView()`, after adding the current constraints, add this:

```
// make sure this controller's view was created as "parentView"
guard let pView = view as? parentView else {
    fatalError("self.view was not instantiated correctly!")
}
// set the bottom constraint of the scroll view in parentView
//  to the top of addHereView (minus 8-points "spacing")
pView.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addHereView.topAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

similarVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Now, when run, we get this result:

[image]

and we can scroll up all the way to the bottom of the paragraph of text:

[image]

and our hierarchy now looks like this:

[image]

The scroll view no longer extends *behind* the collection view.

Comment: Thanks for answer . can we create saparate UIview for MySimilarViewController?  since it not good practice put everything into viewDidLoad function

Comment: @Nar -- *"it not good practice put everything into viewDidLoad function"* -- what do you mean by that? It is standard practice to setup your UI elements in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: but at the same time you are setting up the child view as well . I was arguing but suggested to create separate UIView (class) then Add it into viewDidload like the way it was for parent view . Can we do the same here ?

Comment: @Nar - it is not clear what you are asking. First, why do you have your "Similar Movies" collection view in a separate view controller to begin with? It would seem to make much more sense to add the collection as a subview.

Comment: can I add the  addHereView(after contentStackView) inside parentView ?. then respectfully following rest of the process? but I am not sure How can I pass the child view here . The work it bit complex and I have to use the separate view for simplicity .

Comment: Can we connect on call please? . then I can explain you more details .

Comment: @Nar - you need to take time to clearly write out - *in plain language* - what you're having trouble with. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257069/donmagchat

Comment: Thanks you very much . I have learned lots from you